# How to SQL inner join the following tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
--------
| test |
--------
| id   | 
--------

-----------------------
| testconnection      |
-----------------------
| testid | pharmacyid |
-----------------------

-----------------------------------
| testcontent                     |
-----------------------------------
| id | testID | title | shortened |
-----------------------------------
```

and I need to link `testcontent's` `title` and `shortened` with `testconnection` so that the field `pharmacyid` is linked with my current loop for pharmacies.

Here's what it looks like right now:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pharmacies");
while($pharmacy = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

  and here i'd like to access testcontent's title and shortened for this particular pharmacy

}
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or/and MySQL?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
SELECT cont.title, cont.shortened 
FROM testcontent cont
JOIN testconnection conn
ON cont.testId = conn.testId
```

OR

```
SELECT *, cont.title, cont.shortened 
FROM pharmacies p
JOIN testconnection conn
ON conn.pharmacyid = p.Id
JOIN testcontent cont
ON cont.testId = conn.testId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
SELECT pharmacies.*,
(select title from testcontent where testcontent.testID = testconnection.testid limit 1) as title,
(select shortened from testcontent where testcontent.testID = testconnection.testid limit 1) as shortened  
FROM pharmacies 
left join testconnection on testconnection.pharmacyid = pharmacies.id 
order by pharmacies.id
```

I hope, it will be working.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but this doesn't return any results at all